# How to get Rock smash in pokemon emerald version

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I'm unable to get the rock smash even though I defeated mauville gym leader the person who gives rock smash is saying that when u cut a rock a Pokemon comes flying .how do I get rock smash [image]

Answer (score -1):

You have already received the Rock Smash Hidden Machine.